# Echo all aliases in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, zshrc

Is it possible to force zsh to echo the actual commands referred to by all aliases when they are used?

For example, say that I have the following aliases set:

```
# List direcory contents
alias lsa='ls -lah'
alias l='ls -la'
alias ll='ls -l'
```

When I execute them I would like to see each of them print the actual command that's executed.  For example, I would like to see the following:

```
$ ll
executing: 'ls -l'
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 person  staff  0 Feb 15 13:46 cool.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 person  staff  0 Feb 15 13:46 sweet.html
-rw-r--r--  1 person  staff  0 Feb 15 13:46 test.md
```

Rather than the following:

```
$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 person  staff  0 Feb 15 13:46 cool.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 person  staff  0 Feb 15 13:46 sweet.html
-rw-r--r--  1 person  staff  0 Feb 15 13:46 test.md
```

Is there one command that I can add to my zshrc to get this to happen for all aliases?  I would prefer not to have to modify every alias.

Comment: `set -vx;myAlias args; set+vx` doesn't give what you wnat (excluding the 'executing:' prefix? Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I'm looking for something that I can set once that will apply to all aliases without being coupled to them.  Also, even if I did this for each alias, it would still dump a bunch of information about the aliases and functions used to create my custom zsh prompt.  Thanks for the comment though!  I definitely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are fine with having aliases displayed if alias is the first word present on the command-line you can try to put the following code into your .zshrc:

```
_-accept-line () {
    emulate -L zsh
    local -a WORDS
    WORDS=( ${(z)BUFFER} )
    # Unfortunately ${${(z)BUFFER}[1]} works only for at least two words,
    # thus I had to use additional variable WORDS here.
    local -r FIRSTWORD=${WORDS[1]}
    local -r GREEN=$'\e[32m' RESET_COLORS=$'\e[0m'
    [[ "$(whence -w $FIRSTWORD 2>/dev/null)" == "${FIRSTWORD}: alias" ]] &&
        echo -nE $'\n'"${GREEN}Executing $(whence $FIRSTWORD)${RESET_COLORS}"
    zle .accept-line
}
zle -N accept-line _-accept-line
```

Description (some trivial things skipped):

```
emulate -L zsh # Reset some options to zsh defaults (locally).
               # Makes function immune to user setup.

local -a WORDS # Declare WORDS as an array local to function

${(z)VARNAME}  # Split VARNAME using command-line parser.
               # Things like “"first word" "second word"” get split into 2 words:
               # “"first word"” “"second word"”

$BUFFER        # Variable containing the whole command-line. Can be modified

local -r V     # Declare variable “V” as read-only

$'\e[32m'      # Escape code for green foreground color in most terminals
$'\e[0m'       # Sequence that being echoed to terminal clears out color information

whence -w cmd  # Display type of the command in format “cmd: type”
whence cmd     # If “cmd” is an alias, then this command outputs alias value

zle .accept-line # Call internal zle “accept-line” widget. This must be done or 
               # every command will turn to no-op. You can, of course, replace
               # this with “eval $BUFFER” but I can’t say what will break in this case

zle -N accept-line _-accept-line # Associate widget “accept-line” with function
               # “_-accept-line”. This makes this function responsible for accepting
               # lines.
```

More info in `man zshbuiltins` (`emulate`, `whence`, `local`), `man zshzle` (`zle`, `$BUFFER`), `man zshparam` (`${(z)}`).

Comment: Great work!  I've accepted this as the answer, but I'd love it if you would walk me through it as well.  I'm not sure how you did this, but I'd love to learn.  Thanks either way!

Comment: That's super, super helpful.  Thanks for the explanations!  They are greatly appreciated.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [ZyX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273566/zyx). I modified [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302071/2057154) to making it work for functions as well. Here it is;

```
_-accept-line () {
    emulate -L zsh
    local -a WORDS
    WORDS=( ${(z)BUFFER} )
    # Unfortunately ${${(z)BUFFER}[1]} works only for at least two words,
    # thus I had to use additional variable WORDS here.
    local -r FIRSTWORD=${WORDS[1]}
    local -r GREEN=$'\e[32m' RESET_COLORS=$'\e[0m'
    [[ "$(whence -w $FIRSTWORD 2>/dev/null)" == "${FIRSTWORD}: alias" ]] &&
        echo -nE $'\n'"${GREEN}Executing -> ${$(which $FIRSTWORD)//"$FIRSTWORD: aliased to "/""}${RESET_COLORS}"
    [[ "$(whence -w $FIRSTWORD 2>/dev/null)" == "${FIRSTWORD}: function" ]] &&
        echo -nE $'\n'"${GREEN}Executing -> ${$(which $FIRSTWORD)//"$FIRSTWORD () {
    "/""}${RESET_COLORS}"
    zle .accept-line
}
zle -N accept-line _-accept-line
```

PS: It is developed at short notice. For sure, it can be improved.